# How can I reduce partition on /dev/sda from 80G to 70G

Tags: server

[image]

I tried find out the solution but I am not lucky to resolve. Pleases every body has an idea please share me.
Thank you!

Comment: `/dev/sda` is the device itself, which contains three partitions. It is illogical to resize a storage device, but you can certainly resize `/dev/sda3` to make it smaller or to expand it to use the remaining 20GB of storage space.

Comment: @Matigo is correct, to change the drive size requires replacing the chips on the drive itself, or re-programming them, which is off-topic here as that's a drive & hardware question (and unrelated to the OS).  If however the 80GB drive is software defined (via firmware, or host (virtualization) software and the image you're showing is from a VM, it can be changed by the firmware settings or HOST OS/virtualization software

Comment: @Matigo thank you for your idea now I reduce  /dev/sda3 and it seem look good.